# How insert element in last list?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list `m`. I want to insert an element to the end of this `List`. Please tell me how I can do this.

```
public List<double> m = new List<double>();
m[0].Add(1);
m[1].Add(2);
m[2].Add(3);
```

I want the following output if I add element 7 to the end:

```
1 2 3 7
```

Comment: ehm `m.Add(7);` will add it to the end of the list... what you are doing is trying to call the method Add on a double.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`m.Add(7);` will add it to the end of the list.

What you are doing is trying to call the method Add on a double

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
List<double> m = new List<double>();
m.Add(1);
m.Add(2);
m.Add(3);
m.Add(7);
```

Comment: i want keyword for add directly to end list

Comment: the Add method does add the element to the end of the collection

Answer (score 1):

you should use the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) method.

Example :

```
m.Add(7);
```

This [Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list) shows you how to add elements to the `List` and how to print them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`List<T>.Add()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) method. Like;

> Adds an object to the **end of the** List.

```
List<double> m = new List<double>();
   m.Add(1);
   m.Add(2);
   m.Add(3);
   m.Add(7);
```

Here is a [**`DEMO`**](http://ideone.com/hTpd8k).